# bash script - how to create and store user activity

Tags: bash

i am writing a script so far i created a log-in system but want to create a .db file to store user activity like to store what time they logged in, logged out and when did they order a meal.

this is the small script i wrote

```
#!/bin/bash

function login_system(){

printf "%s\n" "write your username below"
read user

grep ^"$user:" /etc/pass > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
     printf "%s" "confirmed"
     sleep 2
     menu_system
else
     printf "%s" "denied"
     sleep 2
     login_system
fi
}
function menu_system(){
printf "%s\n" "press one to order a breakfast and 2 to exit"
read order

if [ $order -eq 1 ]
then
    .  breakfast
    printf "%s\n" "returing back to menu system"
    sleep 3
    menu_system
else
    exit
fi
}

login_system
exit 0
```

i just dont know how to implement user activity script, i tried researching but couldn't find anything. any guide or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer i manged to work out using printf

```
printf $user >> useractivity.db
printf " " >> useractivity.db
echo $(date) >> useractivity.db
```

use >> just to write on top of it

use > to over write it

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem, so I'll answer with a good resource: [How to redirect script output to a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Redirection).

If this is a question for an actual *production* system, then somebody is crazy. You do not implement systems like this in Bash.